# Retrieve data related to one table from other table without a relation

Tags: django

I have two models user and recordings, But I don't have any relation between them I have stored user id in recordings (there can be multiple recordings of one user). and I want the latest recording of user with user object how can I achieve that

```
class Recording(models.Model):
   userid = models.IntegerField()
```

Comment: please add the models in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi welcome to stackoverflow.
Please ask your question with some of your code.
I think you can try this:

```
users = User.objects.all().extra( select={
        'last_reco':
            'SELECT recordings.field_name FROM recordings WHERE '

            'recordings.userid = '

            'User.id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1',

    })
```

note: recordings is your recording db name
Than you can access last recording with last_reco attr of user object